# Migrating blogger blog to a part of Wordpress site

Tags: blogger

I have an old blog in blogger. Recently I have created a new homepage using Wordpress, and I would like to migrate the old blog into a part of it.
I am familiar with the post regarding migrating blogger into Wordpress, however it covers migrating blogger blog to a new Wordpress site; I would like to add it as a part of an existing site.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: I'd guess the importer would add posts to a site not overwrite all the existing content, which is what you want. Maybe take a backup and try the same process?

Comment: If you need more help can you please include the link to the specific migration steps you're following?